# How to Instatiate a new GameObject to appear in a specific Spawn point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have items appearing on four spawn locations.  When I remove one and it gets destroyed. I want a new item to appear on the spawn point that the item came from.

Creating the first 4 items

```
public class ItemManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Item;
    private float spawnTime = 3f;
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    static public int spawnPointIndex;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
         for(int i = 0; i < spawnPoints.Length; i++)
         {
            spawnPointIndex = i;
            Instantiate(Item, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position,spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
        }
    }   
}
```

I stripped the code.  This allows to destroy the object when a condition is met.
Note: This is on a PreFab GameObject

```
public class ItemController : MonoBehaviour {

    public int spawnLocation;

void Start()
{
    spawnLocation = ItemManager.spawnPointIndex;
 }

void DestroyObject()
 {
        if (whenConditionIsTrue == true){
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            //Invoke new item based on spawn Location
        }
        ObjectMouseDown = false;        
    }
}
```

This is as far as I have got.  I don't quite understand how to get the spawnLocation back to the ItemManager in order to Instatiate a new Item.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a commented and tested script you should find useful. Once an item is destroyed, it spawns a new item to the same point after `spawnTime` seconds. I implemented the delay so that you can actually see the script working.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ItemController Item;
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    private float spawnTime = 3f;

    void Start()
    {
        foreach (Transform spawnPoint in spawnPoints)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Spawn(spawnPoint)); // Spawn is implemented as a coroutine, so that a delay can be added
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Spawn(Transform spawnPoint)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnTime); // See "Coroutines" in Unity documentation
        ItemController newItem = Instantiate(Item, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
        newItem.OnDestroy += () => { StartCoroutine(Spawn(spawnPoint)); }; // Subscribe to the OnDestroy event. When it occurs, run the Spawn coroutine again.
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action OnDestroy;

    void DestroyObject ()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        if (OnDestroy != null) OnDestroy(); // OnDestroy is null if there are no subscribers
    }

    void OnMouseDown () // For testing. Unity calls this method when a collider on this gameObject is clicked
    {
        DestroyObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I get this error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'ItemController'"   I have the red line under the "Instatiate.....rotation"

Comment: @TimCooley `ItemController newItem = Instantiate(Item, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);` should be `ItemController newItem = Instantiate(Item, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation) as ItemController;`

Comment: @Programmer I now get this error: "Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'ItemController' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion"

Comment: @TimCooley The code should work as it is, you are likely using an old version of Unity which lacks a generic version of `Instantiate`. Consider updating.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep looking into what may be the issue.  I am using 5.5

Comment: Strange, I used 5.5 as well so that should be fine. You may try explicitly calling `Instantiate<ItemController>...`. Also double-check that you actually used my code as it is and did not only copy a part of it. Especially notice `public ItemController Item;` vs `public GameObject Item;` in my vs your code.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do here is have an event on ItemController that gets fired when it gets destroyed. The ItemManager can listen for these and handle them.

so for the ItemManager class, just listen and handle the event:

```
public class ItemManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Item;
    private float spawnTime = 3f;
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    static public int spawnPointIndex;

    void Start () {
        for(int i = 0; i < spawnPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            spawnPointIndex = i;
            GameObject itemObject = Instantiate(Item, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position,spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
            itemObject.GetComponent<ItemController>().OnDestroy += SpawnNewItem;
        }
    }   

    public void SpawnNewItem(int i) {
        //spawn new item at index i
    }
}
```

and in the ItemController class, call the event with the relevant info

```
public class ItemController : MonoBehaviour {

    public int spawnLocation;
    public event System.Action<int> OnDestroy;


    void Start()
    {
        spawnLocation = ItemManager.spawnPointIndex;
    }

    void DestroyObject()
    {
        if (whenConditionIsTrue == true){
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            OnDestroy(this.spawnLocation);
        }
        ObjectMouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

this pattern keeps them uncoupled which is what I like when using managers.

Comment: I get the dreaded "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ItemControler.OnMouseUp ()"

Comment: if that is a direct quote from the console, it says "ItemControler" with one 'L', looks unrelated / syntactic

Comment: I don't believe that is related to the issue.  I misspelled it and haven't fixed the issue.  I should have updated the text, my bad :-(